# Admob ads cycling when the phone is locked

Tags: java, android, admob

I have made an app that has a banner ad at the bottom. The app will be used for the most part while the screen is locked. My question is will the banner ads on the screen continue to cycle through on the app when the phone is locked, and if so how do I prevent this from happening so my app does not get banned?

Any Feedback is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdView will automatically stop requesting replacement ads while the screen is not visible. So you don't need to worry.

Mind you, you aren't going to be generating much revenue if you are never showing ads because the screen is always locked.

Comment: Yeah I've thought about that. Do you have any recommendations for types of ads to use that could generate more revenue.

Comment: It really depends on how your app is used. Perhaps showing an interstitial instead? But some apps just don't suit ads at all. You might be better off offering inapp upgrade to provide expanded functionality.